# Custom Query for count_user_posts function

Tags: users

I'm using a plugin to show user post count on my website's backend.Plugin uses "count_user_posts" function in loop to show post count for all users.I want to modify $count value of "count_user_posts" function which is a sql query and append some more conditions at the end. i.e AND post_date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'. Function returns a hook to "get_usernumposts" with $count query , $userId as parameter.

```
//wp function
 function count_user_posts( $userid, $post_type = 'post', $public_only = false ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid, $public_only );
    $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
    /**
     * Filters the number of posts a user has written.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     * @since 4.1.0 Added `$post_type` argument.
     * @since 4.3.1 Added `$public_only` argument.
     *
     * @param int          $count       The user's post count.
     * @param int          $userid      User ID.
     * @param string|array $post_type   Single post type or array of post types to count the number of posts for.
     * @param bool         $public_only Whether to limit counted posts to public posts.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid, $post_type, $public_only );
}

//my function
function author_post_count(){
$where = get_posts_by_author_sql( "post", true, 3, $public_only );
$where .= " AND post_date BETWEEN '2018-03-11' AND '2018-03-13'";
$result = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
return $result;
}

add_filter( 'get_usernumposts', 'author_post_count');
```

is there any way to modify or append "count_user_posts" core function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter callback isn't accepting any arguments from the hook. When you write the callback function you need to include the arguments passed in `apply_filters`, and in your `add_filter()` call you need to specify how many of the arguments you're using:

```
// Accept all 4 arguments provided to callbacks for this filter.
function wpse_296863_author_post_count( $count, $userid, $post_type, $public_only ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid, $public_only );
    $where .= " AND post_date BETWEEN '2018-03-11' AND '2018-03-13'";
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'get_usernumposts', 'wpse_296863_author_post_count', 10, 4 ); // Using 4 arguments.
```

Also note:

- I prefixed the function. Your code should be prefixed with something unique to your project to avoid conflicts.
- You were missing `global $wpdb;`. You can't use `$wpdb->get_var()` without it.
- I passed through the original values from the filter into `get_posts_by_author_sql()`, otherwise all post counts will be for the one user. I assume you'd done this for testing.